# Adding list of symbols chapter

Tags: chapters

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fncychap}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\ChNameVar{\rm\scshape}
\ChNumVar{\rm}
\ChTitleVar{\huge\rm\scshape\centering}
\ChRuleWidth{5pt}
\renewcommand{\DOCH}{%
  \leavevmode\leaders\vrule height \RW\hfill\quad
  \CNV\FmN{\@chapapp}\space \CNoV\Roman{chapter}%
  \quad\leaders\vrule height \RW\hfill\null
  \par\nobreak
  \vskip 10pt
}
\renewcommand{\DOTI}[1]{%
  \hrule\vskip 10pt
  \CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak
  \vskip 10pt
  \hrule
  \vskip 40pt}
\renewcommand{\DOTIS}[1]{%
  \hrule\vskip 10pt
  \CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak
  \vskip 40pt}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Preliminary}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

> I want to add the chapter of symbol as follows

[image]

Comment: Do you want to generate the table automatically based on definitions of symbols in the document? Or do you want to specify the list yourself and just add the page references automatically? In the first case you can look at the `glossaries` package, for the second case just `\pageref` to a `\label` may be sufficient.

Comment: @Marijn I want to specify the list myself.

Comment: @Marijn I write `\pageref{.....}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following prints a manually defined list of symbols in the same style as the chapter headers. The table contains `\pageref` commands that show the page on which a `\label` is defined. The labels are intended to be defined for sections, subsections etc., however in the example below I have just placed them somewhere on the page that mentions the concepts.

The formatting of the table uses the `\tabularx` package which allows to specify the width of the tabular, and also has a `X` column specifier that means 'use the space that is not used by the other columns'.

The formatting of the header is partly copied from the `fncychap` definitions, with the part that prints the text *Chapter n* removed. Note that the font is manually reset to normal size, normal style (no smallcaps) and left aligned (i.e., `\raggedright`) after using the copied code.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fncychap}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\ChNameVar{\rm\scshape}
\ChNumVar{\rm}
\ChTitleVar{\huge\rm\scshape\centering}
\ChRuleWidth{5pt}
\renewcommand{\DOCH}{%
  \leavevmode\leaders\vrule height \RW\hfill\quad
  \CNV\FmN{\@chapapp}\space \CNoV\Roman{chapter}%
  \quad\leaders\vrule height \RW\hfill\null
  \par\nobreak
  \vskip 10pt
}
\renewcommand{\DOTI}[1]{%
  \hrule\vskip 10pt
  \CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak
  \vskip 10pt
  \hrule
  \vskip 40pt}
\renewcommand{\DOTIS}[1]{%
  \hrule\vskip 10pt
  \CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak
  \vskip 40pt}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Preliminary}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\noindent\leavevmode\leaders\vrule height \RW\hfill\null
\par\nobreak
\vskip 10pt
\DOTI{\normalfont List of Symbols}\normalsize\normalfont\raggedright
\setcounter{page}{1}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{2cm}Xl}
$\mathbb{N}$ & set of positive integers & \pageref{posint}\\
$\mathbb{R}$ & set of real numbers & \pageref{realnum}\\
$\mathbb{R}^+$ & set of positive real numbers & \pageref{posreal}\\
$\mathbb{R}^n$ & set of real vectors with dimension $n$ & \pageref{realvec}\\
$\mathbb{C}$ & set of complex numbers & \pageref{complnum}\\
$\mathbb{C}^+$ & right half plane & \pageref{poscompl}\\
$\mathbb{C}^n$ & set of complex vectors with dimension $n$ & \pageref{complvec}\\
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{3cm}
some information about positive integers\label{posint}

some information about real numbers\label{realnum}

some information about complex numbers\label{complnum}

\newpage
\setcounter{page}{16}
some information about positive real numbers\label{posreal}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{133}
some information about real vectors\label{realvec}

some information about complex vectors\label{complvec}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{110}
\begin{definition}
\label{poscompl}
The right half plane is defined as follows: ...
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But just I want to inform you that the pages $1,1,16....$ should be generated automatically based on definitions of symbols in the document.

Comment: That should work the same way: if you have a definition somewhere (using an `amsthm` environment or something similar) you give that a label, and you `\pageref` to that label in the List of Symbols.

Comment: @Student I have added an example definition at the end of the MWE.

Comment: @Student the `tabularx` definition has two arguments. The first is the width of the table (here `\textwidth`, i.e., stretch the table to the full width of the text). The second argument is the column definition, similar to a normal `\tabular`. Here there are three columns, the first is a column of 2cm width (`p{2cm}`), the third is a left-aligned column `l` that takes the width of the widest argument (here the number 133) and the second `X` column means 'use the remaining width for this column'). This `X` column is the reason for using the `tabularx` package.

Comment: If you want a long table that uses two ore more pages then you can either do that manually as you suggest (so put `\end{tabularx}` at the end of the page and `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{2cm}Xl}` at the start of the next page, or use the [`longtable` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf) which is intended for long tables. The only problem is that with `longtable` you cannot use the `X` column definition, so you should manually set the column widths, something like `p{2cm}p{6cm}p{2cm}` for example.

Comment: @Student or use the [`glossaries` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) after all, then everything is automatic, including printing the symbol list.

Comment: @Student at the moment I don't have a lot of time to answer, but I'm sure there will be various people on the site here that can provide a good answer to your new question.